# Order of elements in a formula?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is methane's molecular formula conventionally “CH4”, while water is “H20” (among others)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/974/why-is-methanes-molecular-formula-conventionally-ch4-while-water-is-h20-a)

If I have a formula containing 4 hydrogen atoms and 1 carbon

Should it be written $\small\ce{CH4}$ or $\small\ce{H4C}$?

In general, how do I know the order to put elements in, in a chemical formula?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/974/25) , and [comprehensively answered here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/538/25)

Answer (score 7):

There's something called Hill System. This is the system of writing chemical formulas.
In this system the carbon atoms are first, then hydrogen atoms and then other in alphabetical order. When the formula contains no carbon or hydrogen atoms, then all the elements are sorted alphabetically.

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_system

So it should be: $\ce{CH4}$

However, the Hill system is not the only method of ordering elements in a chemical formula. We can instead choose to list the elements based on their electronegativity. ManishEarth explains this in his answer to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/537/why-is-arsenous-acid-denoted-h3aso3/538#538).

Comment: Where can i see the entire hill system, I would like to memorize it :)

Comment: Here's something you should check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_system

Comment: So its alphabetical?

Comment: like Clorine before sulpher?

Comment: Yes, but there are some exceptions

Comment: @bluepawel Could you give a brief brief summary of the Wikipedia article and incorporate that and the link into your answer?  Comments can get deleted, etc., but if you put the info with the answer it will stay there.  Thanks.