# Why do we write NH3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

We've learnt that the electropositive element is written first. Then why is ammonia written as $\ce{NH3}$ ?

Comment: Perhaps they don't want anyone to think it is a binary acid.

Comment: Ammonia can act as an acid though.

Comment: @Dissenter: Many compounds can act as many things in various weird conditions, but in aqueous solutions ammonia doesn't generally act like an acid.

Comment: See $\ce{CH4}$ , $\ce{BH3}$ etc This rule is generally applied for hydrogen when it is protic: $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{HCl}$, IUPAC has a whole sets of rules that nobody cares to use, especially in nomenclature.

Comment: The same is the case with phosphine.

Comment: Maybe because it is predominantly covalent. Besides, we write other covalent compounds in a similar way. Example - Cl2O7

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to current nomenclature rules, $\ce{H3N}$ would be correct and acceptable.  However some chemical formulas, like $\ce{NH3}$ for ammonia, that were in use long before the rules came out, are still accepted today.

Comment: Are the hydrogens in ammonia really more electropositive than the nitrogen?  Combining H+ ions with anions other than OH- yields compounds which behave as acids in aqueous solutions, but NH3 behaves like a base.

Comment: Yes, hydrogen is more electropositive than nitrogen. The electronegativity of hydrogen is 2.2, while nitrogen is 3.04, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativities_of_the_elements_(data_page)

Comment: I know that in general hydrogen is more elecropositive, but within a covalent structure things sometimes behave in weird ways.  Hydrogen can behave as +1 as in HF or -1 (as in NaH), and nitrogen can be +3 (as in Li3N), -3 (as in NI3), or various other oxidation states.  Is the behavior of ammonia closer to that of a nitride of hydrogen, or a hydride of nitrogen?

Comment: PS -- look at http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/538/7274 for a table which suggests that for purpose of nomenclature, hydrogen's electronegativity is considered to be between that of the first group V element (nitrogen) and the last group VI element (polonium).  See also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/975/7274 which would imply that compounds of hydrogen that are more acidic than water are written with the hydrogen first, and those which are more basic are written with the other element first.

Comment: @supercat $\ce{NaH}$ and $\ce{Li3N}$ are not covalent compounds. And nomenclature does have nothing to do with chemical behaviour. Oxidation states are only a bookkeeping tool.

Comment: @supercat how does oxidation state correlate with electronegativity?

Comment: @Martin: Those aren't covalant, but I think NH3 is.  My point is that while it's common with some covalant compounds to write them according to oxidation state (one writes H2O, for example, rather than OH2), I don't think it's clear that the hydrogens in NH3 should be viewed as having a +1 charge and the nitrogen as -3.  Oxidation states are a bookkeeping tool, true, but the question is about nomenclature rather than chemical behavior, bookkeeping would seem relevant to that.

Comment: The fact that hydrogen is more electropositive than nitrogen is irrelevant to the basic character of ammonia, which is due to the lone pair on nitrogen and not due to hydride ions (as it would be in LiH, for example).

Answer (score 21):

The atomic symbols in a formula may be ordered in various ways. For example, the electronegativity criterion is most often used in binary species (for intermetallic compounds, however, older recommendations prescribed alphabetical ordering rather than by electronegativity).

Section IR-4.4.2.1 of [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (Red Book)*](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf) explains what is meant by the ordering principles ‘electronegativity’:

> IR-4.4.2.1 *Electronegativity*
>
> If electronegativity is taken as the ordering principle in a formula or a part of a formula, the atomic symbols are cited according to *relative* electronegativities, the least electronegative element being cited first. For this purpose, Table VI is used as a guide. By convention, the later an element occurs when the table is traversed following the arrows, the more electropositive is the element.
>
> [image: Table VI Element sequence, Red Book 2005]

This table is also included in the IUPAC Technical Report [Brief guide to the nomenclature of inorganic chemistry. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2015,** *87*(9–10), 1039–1049](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718) as well as in the corresponding four-sided lift-out document, which is available as [supplementary material](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2015.87.issue-9-10/pac-2014-0718/suppl/pac-2014-0718_Suppl.pdf).

Note that hydrogen is placed between the elements of group 16 and the elements of group 15.

Therefore, all the following examples are consistent with the above convention:

$\ce{HF}$
$\ce{HCl}$
$\ce{HBr}$
$\ce{HI}$
$\ce{H2O}$
$\ce{H2S}$
$\ce{NH3}$
$\ce{CH4}$

Note that, according to this convention, the formula for the hydroxide ion should be $\ce{HO-}$ (not $\ce{OH-}$).

Comment: Indeed, the hydroxyl radical as most commonly written (at least in the hard-core free radical chemistry community) conforms to this: $\ce{HO}^\bullet$

Comment: See also, [my answer to this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/974/why-is-methanes-molecular-formula-conventionally-ch%E2%82%84-while-water-is-h%E2%82%82o-a/975#975)

Comment: I think you quoted the wrong paragraph. That one says, elements that came first in the arrow order are cited first. I think you should rather quote IR-2.15.3.1: "In compositional names of binary compounds and corresponding formulae, the element encountered *last* when following the arrow in Table VI is represented *first* in the formula as well as the name."

Comment: The table misses seven elements we now have after Rg. Cmon IUPAC, get the update in!

Comment: Possibly $\ce{OH^-}$ got grandfathered in. In an ionic compound like sodium hydroxide, $\ce{NaOH}$ reflects the true bonding connections (sodium is bonded to oxygen), so the hydroxide ion appears as $\ce{OH^-}$.

Answer (score 12):

The answer of this question lies in the nomenclature of the late 1700’s when chemical knowledge was primitive.  At the time, most chemists agreed on a class of acrid substances, for example vinegar, called “acids”.  Another class of substances reacted with acids to form the “base” of compounds.

When systematizing these compounds, Lavoisier came up with the word oxygen by combining roots which translated meant “to generate acid” because he thought oxygen was used to form acid.  Acid was also thought to be formed by hydrogen as well.  Most of the early chemical formulas for compounds specified both hydrogen and oxygen as the acid forming component.

It was not discovered until 1832 hydrogen, unlike all of the other known elemental gases, shared a property with metal: it was electro-positive. So in the late 1800’s the nomenclature debate surfaced.  Some of the old nomenclature was kept so the opposite nature of acids and bases was reflected in the nomenclature.  This nomenclature was said to facilitate understanding of molecules combining and breaking apart.

As an example, notice how the nomenclature in the following reaction suggests two molecules with opposite properties are sticking together.

$$\ce{ NH3 + HCl -> NH4Cl }$$

The short answer would be early chemist developing nomenclature did not have modern understanding of hydrogen, so hydrogen often was placed in the same location of formulations as oxygen in similar compounds.

Sources:
[Williamson. Remarks on Chemical Nomenclature and Notation. *J. Chem. Soc.* **1864,** *17,* 421–432.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/JS8641700421)

Robert Kane, John William Draper, Elements of chemistry, page 152.