# Covalent Compounds In Written Form

Tags: notation

How do you determine which non-metal is written first in a covalent compound? This has been a confusion for me for quite some time.

Comment: [Why is methane's molecular formula conventionally “CH₄”, while water is “H₂O” (among others)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/974/why-is-methanes-molecular-formula-conventionally-ch%E2%82%84-while-water-is-h%E2%82%82o-a)

Comment: [Why do we write NH3?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16267/why-do-we-write-nh3/43194#43194)

Comment: [Why is arsenous acid denoted H3AsO3?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/537/why-is-arsenous-acid-denoted-h3aso3)

Comment: It's just a convention.

Answer (score 0):

Typical convention for organic molecules is to list carbon first, than hydrogen, and then other elements in alphabetical order. The Merck Index, for example, does it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The way my teacher taught me was C,H,O first, and then in order of decreasing electronegativity.