# How are arsenic compounds removed from drinking water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, purification

I used to live near a volcano where the groundwater contains naturally occurring arsenic compound. Since $\ce{As2O3}$, $\ce{As2S3}$, and $\ce{As4S4}$ are predominantly occurring in drinking water, what are the processes for removing them?

Comment: You may find what you need (happy accident!) in the body of this question http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/472/what-are-the-mechanisms-for-capture-of-ceasiii-and-ceasv-by-magnet.  I don't know that it's a duplicate, I'll let the community decide that.

Comment: (but I wholeheartedly agree with Eric's sentiment below, if you are in fact using this as a method to purify drinking water and not just as a lab exercise, consult an expert in this area for your own safety)

Answer (score 2):

The US Environmental Protection Agency (EPA) has a page dedicated to arsenic in drinking water.  [It contains a section that suggests ways to remove it from water](http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/basicinformation/arsenic.cfm#How%20will%20arsenic%20be%20removed%20from%20my%20drinking%20water?).

Disclaimer: I have no idea if the arsenic removal methods on the linked page actually work.  You should consult someone trained in the science of water purification for definitive information.

Comment: Could you give me the chemical equations for precipitating those Arsenic compounds for my experiments?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not qualified to offer specific suggestions on how to remove toxins thus making water potable.